# A good-enough version of good-enough? When should I stop iterating?

Tags: numerical-analysis

I am studying Abelson and Sussman's *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*, 2/e. I solved the exercise 1.7, which asks for a better stopping criteria for an iterative function to calculate the square root function, and then checked my solution against one that I found on this site: http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.7

The original function iterated until $|\mathtt{guess}^2 - \mathtt{x}| < 0.001$, but the book points out that something better is needed because this does poorly both for very large and for very small `x`.

The solution on schemewiki.org iterates until $|\mathtt{improve(guess, x)-\mathtt{guess}}| < .001\; \mathtt{guess}$, following the book's suggestion of watching "how `guess` changes from one iteration to the next and stopping when the change is a very small fraction of the guess."  (The `improve` function takes a guess and `x` and generates a better guess by averaging the guess with `x`/guess.)

While I instictively went for a precision relative to the magnitude of the radicand. $|\mathtt{guess}^2-x| < 0.001\;\mathtt{x}$.

Both functions seem to yield similar results. Mine seems more obvious and efficient to me. Maybe too obvious... I suppose there is something I missed ?

Comment: Why do you think your version "seems more obvious and efficient"? It
does seem to require an answer twice as precise, i.e. 0.0005 `guess`, though I did not check how the precision improves on each iteration.

Comment: I said "more efficient" because it doesn't call "improve". It really bothers me to call "improve" just to do this test. For all iterations but the last one, it's doing the same work twice. Ok, it can easily be avoided with an "oldguess" variable like shown in the second solution provided on schemewiki. But I still don't like having to boot the recursive procedure with a dummy value for oldguess. I say it's more "obvious" because it doesn't introduce any new elements. But I'm not sure I follow you on " It does require an answer twice as precise", could you help me picture this?

Answer (score 3):

I did not check the code used in Abelson and Sussman's book or wiki.
My guess is that the recursive (or iterative) procedure will somehow
organize to compute `improve(guess,x)` only once. In a recursive
procedure, you just compare the formal parameter which is the previous
guess with the actual value (current guess) that you would pass for a
recursive call, in order to decide whether actually do the call rather
than return it. There may be a difference of one (wasted) iteration
depending on how you do the test.

Regarding the fact that you do the test on $x$ or on $\sqrt x$, or
rather $\mathtt{guess}^2$ or $\mathtt{guess}$, that does not give you the same
precison if you look for the same difference.

One way of explaining it is that $|\mathtt{guess}^2-x|=
|\mathtt{guess}^2-{\sqrt x}^2| = |\mathtt{guess}-\sqrt
x|(\mathtt{guess}+\sqrt x)$
since the second factor has to be positive (at least when relative
imprecision gets small).

Since $\mathtt{guess}$ is supposed to be very close to $\sqrt x$, we know that
$\mathtt{guess}+\sqrt x$ is very close to $2\sqrt x$ or
$2\;\mathtt{guess}$.

Hence $|\mathtt{guess}^2-x|$ is close to $2\sqrt
x\;(\mathtt{guess}-\sqrt x)$, so that the condition
$|\mathtt{guess}^2-x| < 0.001\;x$ can be replaced by
$2\sqrt x\;|\mathtt{guess}-\sqrt x| < 0.001\;x$, i.e.
$|\mathtt{guess}-\sqrt x| < 0.0005\sqrt x$
or, still using the same approximation:
$|\mathtt{guess}-\sqrt x| < 0.0005\;\mathtt{guess}$

This can be further formalized, but the above informal reasonning
gives you the idea.

However, I did not check how fast this conputation is converging, and
what is the difference between $|\mathtt{improve(guess,
x)-\mathtt{guess}}|\;$ and $|\mathtt{guess}-\sqrt x|$, i.e. how fast one
gets closer to the exact answer with each new iteration (assuming the
precision of the arithmetics is still good). Their ratio should also be accounted for. It depends on the formula used for computing the approximation, which I did not look at.